# React Navigation renders all tabs at once

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a bunch of react navigation tabs and one of them opens up the camera. The problem is when the application loads, react navigation instantly renders all the pages at once so the camera is on even if I can't see it. The router file is just a bunch of StackNavigator objects representing each page, loaded into the TabNavigator object.

How can I only render the page I'm going to so that the camera isn't on when it doesn't need to be?

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @pra Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about your specific setup, however the TabNavigator has a `lazy` property for its config.

The Documentation (which is at times confusing) states:

`lazy: whether to lazily render tabs as needed as opposed to rendering them upfront`

You can find the docu [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/docs/api/navigators/TabNavigator.md#tabnavigatorconfig)

Notice: you will notice a bit of delay when showing that view due to its rendering.

Hope this helps

Comment: I considered this but if you switch to another tab the camera page wont be "un-rendered". So your approach will only work once.

Answer (score 0):

set `lazy:false` in  BottomTabNavigatorConfig

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue - the camera was used in **one the main tabs** of my app.
You can use 'useFocusEffect' from '@react-navigation/native':
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

Here is an example:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function cameraOnFocusOnly() {
    const [cameraActive, setCameraActive] = useState(false);
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            // Do something when the screen is focused
            setCameraActive(true);

            return () => {
                // Do something when the screen is unfocused
                setCameraActive(false);
            };
        }, [])
    );

    return (
        <View>
            {cameraActive && <CameraComponent/>}
        </View>
    );
}
```